# Ubuntu 17.04 suspend problems

Tags: suspend, 17.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04
Whenever i try to resume the screen after suspend the screen the Desktop gets messed up like this

[image]

I thought it could be bug but see no other posts about this anywhere.
It comes back to normal when i logout an login again.
Anyone else facing this problem?

I use nvidia drivers and this is my graphics driver

[image]

Comment: Add your system graphic information, are you using nvidia? didd you installed any specific driver for your graphic card from additional drivers, etc?

Comment: Yes i use nvidia graphics drivers. But I installed them before updating to 17.04.

Comment: Have you read this: 

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms/+bug/1681566

Comment: Okay! I hadn't seen this. But the reinstall solution worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an issue with the nvidia driver and kernel 4.10.

I resolved by installing recently released driver 381.09

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-381
```

Comment: 381.09 seems to fix the problem for me too.